# Move page item to show under custom post type admin menu

Tags: php, wordpress, admin

I have this page that shows under Appearance top menu in wordpress admin. I have created another top menu section called shots (through creating a custom post type) and want this page to go under there.

Which part of my code do I edit? I have gone to the codex of wordpress and it show me a way by 
     add_submenu_page( $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug,     $function)

but the code I have does not have an `add_submenu_page()` function for me to change:

```
<?php
// Default options values
$sa_options = array(
    'footer_copyright'   => '&copy; ' . date( 'Y' ) . ' ' . get_bloginfo( 'name' ),
    'intro_text'         => '',
    'featured_cat'       => '',
    'layout_view'        => 'fixed',
    'author_credits'     => true
);

if( is_admin() ) : // Load only if we are viewing an admin page

    function sa_register_settings()
    {
        // Register settings and call sanitation functions
        register_setting( 'sa_theme_options', 'sa_options', 'sa_validate_options' );
    }


    add_action( 'admin_init', 'sa_register_settings' );

    // Store categories in array
    $sa_categories[0] = array(
        'value'  => 0,
        'label'  => ''
    );
    $sa_cats = get_categories();
    $i = 1;
    foreach( $sa_cats as $sa_cat ) :
        $sa_categories[$sa_cat->cat_ID] = array(
            'value'  => $sa_cat->cat_ID,
            'label'  => $sa_cat->cat_name
        );
        $i++;
    endforeach;

    // Store layouts views in array
    $sa_layouts = array(
        'fixed'  => array(
            'value'  => 'fixed',
            'label'  => 'Fixed Layout'
        ),
        'fluid'  => array(
            'value'  => 'fluid',
            'label'  => 'Fluid Layout'
        ),
    );

    function sa_theme_options()
    {
    // Add theme options page to the addmin menu
        add_theme_page( 'Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'edit_theme_options', 'theme_options', 'sa_theme_options_page' );
    }


    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'sa_theme_options' );

    // Function to generate options page
    function sa_theme_options_page()
    {
        global $sa_options, $sa_categories, $sa_layouts;

        if( !isset( $_REQUEST['updated'] ) )
            $_REQUEST['updated'] = false; // This checks whether the form has just been submitted. 
        ?>

        <div class="wrap">

                <?php screen_icon();
                echo "<h2> WP Live-shot" . __( ' Theme Options' ) . "</h2>";
                // This shows the page's name and an icon if one has been provided 
                ?>

                <?php if( false !== $_REQUEST['updated'] ) : ?>
                <div class="updated fade"><p><strong><?php _e( 'Options saved' ); ?></strong></p></div>
        <?php endif; // If the form has just been submitted, this shows the notification  ?>

            <form method="post" action="options.php">

        <?php $settings = get_option( 'sa_options', $sa_options ); ?>

        <?php settings_fields( 'sa_theme_options' );
        /* This function outputs some hidden fields required by the form,
          including a nonce, a unique number used to ensure the form has been submitted from the admin page
          and not somewhere else, very important for security */
        ?>

                <table class="form-table"><!-- Grab a hot cup of coffee, yes we're using tables! -->

                    <tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="footer_copyright">Footer Copyright test</label></th>
                        <td>
                            <input id="footer_copyright" name="sa_options[footer_copyright]" type="text" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $settings['footer_copyright'] ); ?>" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="intro_text">Intro Text</label></th>
                        <td>
                            <textarea id="intro_text" name="sa_options[intro_text]" rows="5" cols="30"><?php echo stripslashes( $settings['intro_text'] ); ?></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="featured_cat">Featured Category</label></th>
                        <td>
                            <select id="featured_cat" name="sa_options[featured_cat]">
        <?php
        foreach( $sa_categories as $category ) :
            $label = $category['label'];
            $selected = '';
            if( $category['value'] == $settings['featured_cat'] )
                $selected = 'selected="selected"';
            echo '<option style="padding-right: 10px;" value="' . esc_attr( $category['value'] ) . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $label . '</option>';
        endforeach;
        ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr valign="top"><th scope="row">Layout View</th>
                        <td>
        <?php foreach( $sa_layouts as $layout ) : ?>
                                <input type="radio" id="<?php echo $layout['value']; ?>" name="sa_options[layout_view]" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $layout['value'] ); ?>" <?php checked( $settings['layout_view'], $layout['value'] ); ?> />
                                <label for="<?php echo $layout['value']; ?>"><?php echo $layout['label']; ?></label><br />
        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr valign="top"><th scope="row">Author Credits</th>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="author_credits" name="sa_options[author_credits]" value="1" <?php checked( true, $settings['author_credits'] ); ?> />
                            <label for="author_credits">Show Author Credits</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>

                <p class="submit"><input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Save Options" /></p>

            </form>

        </div>

        <?php
    }


    function sa_validate_options( $input )
    {
        global $sa_options, $sa_categories, $sa_layouts;

        $settings = get_option( 'sa_options', $sa_options );

        // We strip all tags from the text field, to avoid vulnerablilties like XSS
        $input['footer_copyright'] = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $input['footer_copyright'] );

        // We strip all tags from the text field, to avoid vulnerablilties like XSS
        $input['intro_text'] = wp_filter_post_kses( $input['intro_text'] );

        // We select the previous value of the field, to restore it in case an   //  invalid      entry has been given
        $prev = $settings['featured_cat'];
        // We verify if the given value exists in the categories array
        if( !array_key_exists( $input['featured_cat'], $sa_categories ) )
            $input['featured_cat'] = $prev;

        // We select the previous value of the field, to restore it in case an invalid entry has been given
        $prev = $settings['layout_view'];
        // We verify if the given value exists in the layouts array
        if( !array_key_exists( $input['layout_view'], $sa_layouts ) )
            $input['layout_view'] = $prev;

        // If the checkbox has not been checked, we void it
        if( !isset( $input['author_credits'] ) )
            $input['author_credits'] = null;
        // We verify if the input is a boolean value
        $input['author_credits'] = ( $input['author_credits'] == 1 ? 1 : 0 );

        return $input;
    }


endif;  // EndIf is_admin()
?>
```

It's a bit too complex for me to rebuild using the `add_submenu_page()` function, can anyone help? The name of the custom post type is `wp_live_shot`.

Comment: Too many code posted which does not explain the real problem. But am I the only one who thinks it's completely unacceptable to initialize function only IF certain statement is true. It should be initalized and then used if smth true. I mean. You have `function submenu($param1) { doSmth... ;}` then `if (isAdmin()) { submenu($param1); }`

Comment: Not really a problem as per say, the code get the job done in getting a options page created , but its under the wrong tree, (appearance) where i want it to be under Shots (custom post type).

Comment: Your code has wrong output because you have total mess of PHP and HTML, you depend on functions which create HTML, echo them, initialize new ones, echo HTML and so on. Stick to one file where functions are defined, then in your template file just control by statements. E.g.: `<div class="x">First menu</div><?php if(isAdmin()): ?><div class="submenu">submenu</div><?php endif; ?>.` It's really hard to debug code like yours. Also we are here to suggest better practices. So you won't have that headache if you design your code better

Comment: @ Royal Bg the code is correct and works but i will take hid of your advice, along this section    function sa_theme_options() {
 // Add theme options page to the addmin menu
 add_theme_page( 'Theme Options', 'Plugin Options', 'edit_theme_options', 'theme_options', 'sa_theme_options_page' );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'sa_theme_options' );   there is a key which tells the page were to appear, thats what i cant figure out

Comment: This is the core broken logic. Wordpress is total spaghetti. You should not rely in function which creates HTML. Of if you do, get rid of the other code. Stick to only HTML and simple conditions/loops in the template file. And if your functions are recieving this params only, maybe there's no key to tell them where to render.

Comment: Hi, I passed the code through NetBeans auto-formatting. It was very hard to understand what was going on... Use a nice IDE and your life will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

What the function `add_theme_page()` really does is this:

```
// wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L1104
function add_theme_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function = '' ) {
    return add_submenu_page( 'themes.php', $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function );
}
```

So, it will be as easy as replacing your

```
add_theme_page( 'Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'edit_theme_options', 'theme_options', 'sa_theme_options_page' );
```

for

```
add_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=wp_live_shot', 'Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'edit_theme_options', 'theme_options', 'sa_theme_options_page' );
```